# How to trim white spaces from the output in sybase ase

Tags: database, sybase

Question: How can i get rid of the white spaces between columns in the following output? Please help

```
output:
================================================
db_name                                                      data_size                                       data_used                        data_used_pct                           log_size                                        log_used                                         log_used_pct
 ------------------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ---------------------------------------
 E30                                                                                                     1026                                8                                       1                                             100                                                1                                       1
 SM1                                                                                                       60                                4                                       6                                              20                                                1                                       1
 master                                                                                                    26                               12                                      43                                            NULL                                             NULL                                      43
========================================================================
```

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

The width of the column based on the width of the datatype. So if you select from a column which has varchar(255) then you would have 255 chars width. You need to reduce the width of the datatype if you want to reduce the width of the column. For example:

```
select 
  convert(varchar(30), db_name) as db_name,
  convert(numeric(10), data_size) as data_size, 
  ... 
from table
```